# 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000000

Tags: c++

Снова возник вопрос на этот раз задание реализовать Генератор случайных чисел равномерным распределением.
Информации об этом в интернете много.
Вопрос такой почему он ругается на указанной строке.
Класс открытый,да он абстрактный так как мне просто нужно реализовать и инициализировать значения для подсчёта случайных чисел.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class IRandomGenerator
{
public: 
    virtual int randomIntValue() = 0;// значение от 0 до max int      
   virtual double randomDoubleValue() = 0;//значение от 0 до 1 
    IRandomGenerator(void)
    {  }   
    virtual ~IRandomGenerator(void)
    {}
};

 long int m;;///2 в 24 степени.
    int diap1,diap2,kolvo;
    int calculateRandom();
    bool m_bordersIsSet;//границы интервала
    int a,b,c0,x;
    typedef std::map<double, int>::iterator iterator_type;
    int digitsAfterPoint;
    bool useDoubleRandom;
    IRandomGenerator* m_random;

void initValues(const int &initialValue, const bool &borderIsSet, const int &diap1 = 0, const int &diap2 = m);

void initValues(const int &initialValue, const bool& borderIsSet, const int &min, const int &max)
{
    x = initialValue;
    a=1664525;
    c0=1013904;
    m=16777216;
    diap1=min;
    diap2=max + 1;
    m_bordersIsSet=borderIsSet;
}

int randomIntValue()
{
    x = calculateRandom();
    if (m_bordersIsSet)
    {
        int a = diap2 - diap1;
        int b = x % a;
        int c0 = diap1 + b;
        return c0;
    }
    return x;
}

double randomDoubleValue()
{
    x = calculateRandom();
    return x / (1. * m -1);
}

int calculateRandom()
{
   return std::abs((int)((a*x + c0) % m));
}

void UniformDistribution(const int &initialValue, const int &min, const int &max)
{
    initValues(initialValue, true, min, max);
}

void calculateRandoms()
{
    cout<<"Задайте количество иттераций:\t";
    int iterationCount;
    cin>>iterationCount;
    std::map<double, int> vals;
    int multiPlierForRound = pow(10, (double)digitsAfterPoint);
    for (int i = 0; i < iterationCount; ++i)
    {

        const double key = useDoubleRandom? std::ceil(m_random->randomDoubleValue() * multiPlierForRound) / multiPlierForRound : m_random->randomIntValue();    –––––––– Вот на этой строке ругается--------    
        vals[key] +=1;
    }
    int maxHitCount = 0;
    for (iterator_type it = vals.begin(); it != vals.end(); ++it)
    {
        maxHitCount = maxHitCount > it->second ? maxHitCount : it->second;
    }
    for (iterator_type it = vals.begin(); it != vals.end(); ++it)
    {
        double groupName = it->first;
        cout<<endl<< groupName << "|\t" << it->second << "\t";
        double stickCount = it->second/ (1. *maxHitCount) * 30;
        for (int j = 0; j < stickCount; ++j)
        {
            cout<<"|";
        }
        double hitPersent = it->second / (1. * iterationCount);;
        cout<<" [" <<hitPersent * 100 << " %]";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}


void inputdata(int diap1,int diap2,int kolvo)
{
    cout<<"Линейный конгруэнтный  ГПСЧ"<<endl;
    cout<<"Введите количество чисел"<<endl;
    cin>>kolvo;
    cout<<"Начало интервала"<<endl;
    cin>>diap1;
    cout<<"Конец интервала"<<endl;
    cin>>diap2;
    UniformDistribution(kolvo, diap1, diap2);
    calculateRandoms();
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    inputdata(diap1,diap2,kolvo);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну раз он пытается читать по адресу 0 - значит у вас указатель на какой то объект к которомы вы пытаетесь обратится равен NULL

Comment: Не запуская, вижу ошибку в следующей строке, после той что вы указали: `vals[key] +=1;` - ошибка в том, что вектор у вас пустой и здесь вы пытаетесь обратиться к несуществующему элементу вектора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё программа работает, всем спасибо.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class IRandomGenerator
{
public:

    virtual int randomIntValue() = 0;// значение от 0 до max int   

   virtual double randomDoubleValue() = 0;//значение от 0 до 1

    IRandomGenerator(void)
    {

    }

    virtual ~IRandomGenerator(void)
    {
    }
};

class UniformDistribution:public IRandomGenerator
{
    //public:
   // UniformDistribution(const int& initialValue = 0xFFFF);
    //UniformDistribution(const int& initialValue, const int& min, const int& max);


    // IRandomGenerator interface
public:
    //virtual int randomIntValue();
    //virtual double randomDoubleValue();
//private:
    /// void initValues(const int &initialValue, const bool &borderIsSet, const int &min = 0, const int &max = 16777216);

    //const так как не изменяет ни один член класса

public:
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int c;
    unsigned int m;

    //границы
    int diap1;
    int diap2;
    bool m_bordersIsSet;

    void UniformDistribution::initValues(const int &initialValue, const bool& borderIsSet, const int &min, const int &max)
{
    x = initialValue;
    a=1664525;
    c=1013904223;
    m=16777216;
    diap1=min;
    diap2=max + 1;
    m_bordersIsSet=borderIsSet;
}

    UniformDistribution::UniformDistribution(const int &initialValue, const int &min, const int &max)
{
    initValues(initialValue, true, min, max);
}

//UniformDistribution::UniformDistribution(const int &initialValue)    
//{
 //   initValues(initialValue,false);
//}


int UniformDistribution::randomIntValue()
{
    x = calculateRandom();
    if (m_bordersIsSet)
    {
        int a = diap2 - diap1;
        int b = x % a;
        int c = diap1 + b;
        return c;
    }
    return x;
}

double UniformDistribution::randomDoubleValue()
{
    x = calculateRandom();
    return x / (1. * m -1);
}


int UniformDistribution::calculateRandom() const
{
    return std::abs((int)((a*x + c) % m));  
}
};







class Menu
{
    public:

    void printMenuMessage();
    bool isQuitCommandRecived();
    void processCommand();
public:
    IRandomGenerator* m_random;
    int digitsAfterPoint;
    bool useDoubleRandom;

    typedef std::map<double, int>::iterator iterator_type;

Menu::Menu()
    :  m_random(NULL)
    , digitsAfterPoint(1)
    , useDoubleRandom(true)
{

}

Menu::~Menu()
{
    if (m_random)
    {
        delete m_random;
    }
}

void Menu::initUniformDistribution()
{
    cout<<endl<<"Введите начальное значение:";
    int initial;
    cin>>initial;
            int start, stop;
            cout<<"Начало диапазона: ";cin>>start;
            cout<<"Конец диапазона: ";cin>>stop;
            m_random = new UniformDistribution(initial, start, stop);
            useDoubleRandom = false;           
    }


void Menu::calculateRandoms()
{
    cout<<"Задайте количество итераций:\t";
    int iterationCount;
    cin>>iterationCount;

    std::map<double, int> vals;

    int multiPlierForRound = pow(10, (double)digitsAfterPoint);

    for (int i = 0; i < iterationCount; ++i)
    {

        const double key = useDoubleRandom
            ? std::ceil(m_random->randomDoubleValue() * multiPlierForRound) / multiPlierForRound
                : m_random->randomIntValue();
        vals[key] +=1;
    }
    int maxHitCount = 0;
    for (iterator_type it = vals.begin(); it != vals.end(); ++it)
    {
        maxHitCount = maxHitCount > it->second ? maxHitCount : it->second;
    }
    for (iterator_type it = vals.begin(); it != vals.end(); ++it)
    {
        double groupName = it->first;
        cout<<endl<< groupName << "|\t" << it->second << "\t";
        double stickCount = it->second/ (1. *maxHitCount) * 30;
        for (int j = 0; j < stickCount; ++j)
        {
            cout<<"|";
        }
        double hitPersent = it->second / (1. * iterationCount);;
        cout<<" [" <<hitPersent * 100 << " %]";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    Menu menu;
    menu.initUniformDistribution();
    menu.calculateRandoms();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```